# Serverside DataTables returning extra pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

When I am calling a serverside DataTables search, I get back one item and this is the response of the AJAX call:

```
{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 1, recordsFiltered: 18,…}
 data: [{...}]
 draw: 1
 recordsFiltered: 18
 recordsTotal: 1
```

And DataTables recognizes this:

```
Showing 1 to 10 of 18 entries (filtered from 1 total entries)
```

This is my current configuration (I'm currently using pipelining as described here: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
        url: '/url',
        pages: 5 // number of pages to cache,
    }),
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "columns": columnData,
    "order": [[1, "desc"]]
});
```

When I call `table.page.info()` in the Chrome browser console, I get

```
{page: 0, pages: 2, start: 0, end: 10, length: 10, …}
end: 10
length: 10
page: 0
pages: 2
recordsDisplay: 18
recordsTotal: 1
serverSide: true
start: 0
```

Based on the previous information and the fact that Datatables correctly searches, I think my server-side implementation is correct. However, I don't know what is causing Datatables to display two pages instead of one with ten records per page.

Comment: how can recordsDisplay >  totalRecords?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Comment: Hi @AnimalTesting, i added answer. if it helps, then upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this help you to understand.

`recordsTotal` is used to display total records and set pagination for number of records. Datatable has internal function to set pagination based on `recordsTotal`.

 while`recordsDisplay` is used to display records on particular page.
  
 when you click on pagination, for server side it fetch new records based on length and offset. 

 **So, The problem in your code is that you have `recordsDisplay` is 18, and `recordsTotal` is 1. which is not possible.**

--> it is never possible that `recordsDisplay` > `recordsTotal`.

Answer (score 0):

After re-checking the server-side code and with the help of yash's comment, I realized I switched the return values of `recordsTotal` and `recordsDisplay`.